# In d3 on blur event is not working in firefox only

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to use the `blur` event in d3, which is working fine in chrome and safari browser, but unfortunately, it is not working in firefox.
The purpose of using blur is to reset the other items after clicking outside the canvas.
Any workaround solution to the problem?

```js
var width = 500;
var height = 400;
var svg = d3.select("#viz")
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)
  .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
  .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height)
  .append('g');
var outer = svg.append('g')
  .attr('transform', "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")")
  .attr('class', 'boundry');

var boundry = outer.append("svg:circle")
  .attr("r", 100)
  .attr("class", "primary-parent")
  .attr('fill', 'red')
  .attr('stroke', "yellow")
  .attr("stroke-width", 5);

d3.selectAll('.primary-parent').on('click', function() {
  alert("click event fired");
}).on("blur", function() {
  alert("blur event fired");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<div id="viz"></div>
```

Comment: also not working in IE11

Comment: This seems to have been discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25201695/svg-a-element-not-receiving-focus-correctly-in-firefox-and-ie11).

Answer (score 1):

I don't like this solution, but similar behavior to what you are looking for could be implemented by tracking the focused object yourself and removing focus by attaching a temporary click listener to the window object. So the event code becomes something like:

```
var focused;
var setWindowClickListener = function(e) {
    if (e.target !== focusedElement) {
    focusedElement = null;
    window.removeEventListener('click', setWindowClickListener);
    alert('blur');
  }
};

d3.selectAll('.primary-parent')
.on('click', function() {
    alert('click');
    focusedElement = d3.event.target;
    window.addEventListener('click', setWindowClickListener);
});
```

See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ju0eLmgy/1/).

Naturally, this is not ideal, since we are attaching an arbitrary event listener, and this does not work with keyboard blur - the fundamental feature of the blur event. However, it may work for you with some adjustments.