# Targeting pseudo elements with d3 - is it possible?

Tags: d3.js

This works just fine:

```
d3.selectAll('ul li')
  .style('background', 'red');
```

However, this doesn't do anything:

```
d3.selectAll('ul li:before')
  .style('background', 'red');
```

The selection returned by `d3.selectAll('ul li:before')` is empty, even though the `:before` elements do exist, and have some existing CSS styling.

Is it possible to target pseudo elements with d3?

And if it is, a quick follow up question: How would I target all the `:before` pseudo-elements **directly on** (ie, not **within**) a particular selection?

Eg:

```
var listItems = d3.selectAll('ul li');
var beforeElements = listItems.selectAll('&:before'); // SASS-style selector obviously won't work here
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not possible the way you're trying to do it.

The [querySelector methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), on which D3's select functions are based, never return results for pseudo-element selectors.

Furthermore, the D3 `style` method works by setting inline style attributes on the selected elements.  You cannot set inline styles for pseudo-elements, so setting the style attribute on the parent element won't work either.

What you *could* do is select the parent elements, give them a class name, and then use CSS stylesheet rules to target the `:before`/`:after` pseudo-elements for objects of that class.  If you would need to dynamically create the CSS rules, [see this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21323751/3128209).

However, it is probably easiest to just create empty `<span>` or `<div>` child elements, and style those instead.

Comment: Thanks. I've gone with the empty span option.