# How to remove/change dynamically created CSS class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

**Background**,

There are some elements where CSS animations needs to be applied. However these CSS needs to be generated on the fly as calculation needs to be done from JavaScript code.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720320/how-to-dynamically-create-css-class-in-javascript-and-apply) question clarifies how to dynamically add a CSS. Now the question is, how do I remove or replace a CSS generated following the accepted answer?

Just to be clear, it's nothing to do with removing a class from element. I need to remove it from the page so that animations will stop from elements with class. At some time later I can alter the CSS and re-register class so that associated elements are animated in different way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove CSS class from element with JavaScript (no jQuery)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155737/remove-css-class-from-element-with-javascript-no-jquery)

Comment: Not a duplicate, this is not about removing CSS from element, but removing class from the page.

Comment: Then explain yourself better, coz based on the 4 answers that are stating how to remove the class from the element it seems that's what you're asking.

Comment: Question updated... hope it's clear enough now

Comment: Okay then so Possible duplicate of [How to change/remove css classes definitions at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730048/how-to-change-remove-css-classes-definitions-at-runtime)

Comment: Not really, the that question talks about class in a stylesheet. This one is class added dynamically.

Comment: It shouldn't matter as any class would be in that DOM structure

Comment: I think that the link on the answer has enough information for you to achieve what you're trying

Comment: Well the answer referring to 'document.styleSheets[i].cssRules' but this class is not inside a stylesheet, which is why I asked the question in the first place

Answer (score 1):

document.getElementById('someElementId').className = '';

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It removes class from the element, I need to remove the class (added dynamically) from the page

Answer (score 0):

Edit.

You can remove it from the element's class list

```
document.getElementById("myelementsid").classList.remove("classname");
```

Comment: If you want to toggle between two class name , use `$(#id_name).toggleClass('class_name1  class_name2');`

Comment: ?? I'm answering the OP's question, and without having him to include anything extra (like jQuery that you're using).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It removes class from the element, I need to remove the class (added dynamically) from the page

Answer (score 0):

Here you are full documentation to do it with jQuery
https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/
with this, you can remove one or more classes

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It removes class from the element, I need to remove the class (added dynamically) from the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the specific style from the page you can do it like the following snippet:

```
$('link[title=stylesheettitle]').prop('disabled',true);
```

**OR**

```
$('link[title="stylesheettitle"]').remove();
```

**Java Script**

```
var style = document.getElementById('styleID');
style.parentNode.removeChild(style );
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to change element, I need to remove the class, to stop css animations, and add it after an interval with different parameters (for example animation duration / no of pixels transformed/ etc...), and the class does not reside in a style sheet, it's added dynamically (see the linked question)

Comment: @LowFlyingPelican what did you try ?

Comment: @LowFlyingPelican this what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125453/modifying-css-class-property-values-on-the-fly-with-javascript-jquery