# Root css is not working for IE browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

I use root css to set my background image. It is supported by all other browser but in IE 9+ I am not able to apply background image to css. May be browser is supported for root css.
I am setting root css variable using javascript.
I use LESS and Sass css also but did'nt get any way to set css global variable via javascript or JQuery.
This is my css code:-

```
:root{
--mainbgimage: url("image.jpg");
}
body{
background-image: var(--mainbgimage);
}
```

Is there any way to make this code supported for IE browser
Javascript code

```
var image = // image fetched from database;
document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--mainbgimage", image);
```

Comment: please show us how are you setting :root via javascript

Comment: As CSS Variables are not supported in IE (see answer below), you can't set the CSS Variable "--mainbgimage" with setProperty in IE as well.

Answer (score 1):

CSS Variables are not supported up to IE 11. See http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables

You need to reference the url to the image directly in the body class, e.g.

```
body{
background-image: url("image.jpg");
}
```

If you set the image url in javascript, then you need to access the body element directly in javascript and change the image url.

Comment: any other way to set css data dynamically. I want set that value in multiple class in css

Comment: If you know before, which elements will get this background-image, then just add an additional class to them, e.g. '.dynamic-background-image'. Then in javascript, create the class and add the background-image url to it (see. e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125453/modifying-css-class-property-values-on-the-fly-with-javascript-jquery)