# How to change the CSS attributes inside the particulate class using only JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I know how to change the class of div using JavaScript `classList.add` and `classList.add`. But my purpose is change data inside the class using JavaScript.

as example,

let think I have class called example,

```
.example {
position:bsolute;
width:100;
}
```

Is it possible change the width of example class using JavaScript. If yes, how can I change it?

> Pure JavaScript only. cant use any libraries.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125453/modifying-css-class-property-values-on-the-fly-with-javascript-jquery

Comment: You mean something like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19613731/8683285

Comment: Did you got your answer?

Comment: I need to do it without any JavaScript libraries.

Comment: Please add relevant requirements like *no libraries*, etc in your original question itself. I recommend that you create a new question with your requirements and also with your attempt as well.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here is a javascript solution:

```js
var example = document.getElementByClassName("example");
example.style.width = "50px";
```

Comment: The question wasn't tagged with jQuery