# how do i add a class to my h1 with javascript?

Tags: javascript, class

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add a class to a given element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507138/how-do-i-add-a-class-to-a-given-element)

I'd like to have JavaScript add a class to my `h1` elements automatically.

How would I add JavaScript to replace the `h1` element with `h1="classs"` etc?

Comment: been asked my times before. 

check [add class to element][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Jquery it's simple. Loop all of the h1 elements adding the classname to it

```
$(function(){
  $('h1').each(function(){
    $(this).addClass('classname');
  });
});
```

Or if you want to add a class per specific element ID

```
  $(function(){
    $('#eleID').addClass('classname');
  });
```

Comment: Shorter: `$('h1').addClass('class')`

Answer (score 3):

First of all, get the element by ID or by TagName. And at second, use .className = "your-class".

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");

for (i = 0; i < h1.length; i++) {
    h1[i].className += ' classs';
}
```

[Tested on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yMHSu/2/)

Comment: That won't work. `getElementsByTagName` returns a `NodeList`, not a single element. You have to iterate over the list.

Comment: Ah, cheers Felix.... jQuery spaz over here ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
element.setAttribute("class", classname)
```

Where `classname` is the name of the class you want to add and `element` is your `h1` tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1 id='needsName'>My header</h1>
```

Javascript code here

```
document.getElementById("needsName").className = 'the_name_you_want';
```