# Dialogs in Phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova

I am new to phonegap.I want display dialogs in application.How can i display dialog .I have goggled for tutorials but i am not able to find.Please any one please give guidance or tutorials to display dialogs.Thanks in advance....

Comment: Maybe try reading the Phonegap documentation first http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html#Notification

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
alert("on device ready!!!!");
```

or

```
navigator.notification.alert("PhoneGap is working");
```

Comment: Thanks u so much.I am looking for dialog with image,button and text.

Comment: i got dialog with image,text and buttons.I have used REDIPS.dialog

Answer (score 3):

You could use Fancybox javascript to do this:

[Fancybox javascript](http://fancybox.net)

You can create dialogs with everything you need inside.

Answer (score 1):

I've made dialogs by using absolutely positioned <div> which show or hide depending whether dialog is open or closed.

**In my index.html**

```
<div id="hellodlg" class="dialog hidden">
Hello
<button class="closedlg">close</button>
</div>
<button class="openclosedlg">open/close</button>
```

**in style**

```
<style>
.dialog {
position:absolute;
left:50%; // position in the middle
margin-left: -5em; // move left so that dialog is in the middle
top: 2em;
width: 10em;
height:10em;
background:blue;
border: 1px solid black:
}

.hidden {
display:none;
}
</style>
```

**in script using jquery [(see how to add class without jquery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507138/how-do-i-add-a-class-to-a-given-element)**

```
<script>
// open dialog
$(".openclosedlg").click(function() { $(".dialog").toggleClass("hidden");});

// listen for button
$(".closedlg").click(function() { $(".dialog").addClass("hidden");});
</script>
```

[Here is a complete example](http://www.creabros.com/files/test.html)

Comment: you know you can just use the jquery `toggle();` function?

Comment: You are right... learning all the time. I had forgotten about toggle.

Answer (score 0):

Use [JQM](http://jquerymobile.com)

as a designing framework which is most suitable companion for phonegap.