# set display property flex on element cross browser

Tags: javascript, css

Ho can I set these properties:

```
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
```

On an element with javascript. I usually do it like so:

```
var element = document.getElementById("#element")

element.style.display = "flex";
```

But what about the rest of the properties in there, what could I do to apply those ?

Comment: Do the same, add the same lines for each but replace `flex` for the other properties?

Comment: Won't that overwrite the previous styles I just applied ? Shouldn't I get the computed styles first and then add ?

Comment: @putvande That's not a good idea, only the last one would be a value of `display`.

Comment: @Teemu ~ precisely why I asked this question ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can develope this code snippet further:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('id_of_element_to_check'),
    dispValue = ['-webkit-box', '-moz-box', '-ms-flexbox', '-webkit-flex', 'flex'],
    n;      
for (n = 0; n < dispValue.length; n++) {
    elem.style.display = dispValue[n];
    if (window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).display === dispValue[n]) {
        break;
    }
}
```

The idea is, that `window.getComputedStyle()` won't return invalid values. The check can be also put in a `while` condition, but maybe it's safest to do within a `for` loop. I tested this in Chrome28, FF22 and IE10.

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enTtY/).

Comment: ah yes, i did a different mistake. Sorry, I'll delete the comment. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

What about adding in css  :

```
.flexbox{
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
}
```

And then adding a class ".flexbox" to the element like said in this topic :

[How do I add a class to a given element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507138/how-do-i-add-a-class-to-a-given-element)

Comment: I'm not going to use a class for this particular case