# How to add a class to an element using jQuery and javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, navigation

I have the HTML code as given below to add the navigation to my site. (Note that the list is nested)

```
<div id="navigation">
       <ul>
        <li><a href="default.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About us</a></li>
        <li><a href="help.html">Help</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">DropDown</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="last"><a href="#">A Last Link Text</a></li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

I want to show the currently active page link in new color. So the corresponding list item should have the class **active** and I use the CSS to change the color. For example, if the **default.html** is the currently opened page, the code should be `<li class=“active”><a href="default.html">Home</a></li>`.

How to do that in jQuery and JavaScript (I need both for two different websites). 
Can anyone help me?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please post your JavaScript code in the question so we can help.

Comment: Actually, I don't know javascript and jquery. But, I came to know that we can select an element and add class using the both scripts.That is why I am asking.

Comment: Then you need to do bit of research first. We expect code in questions that ask for code. This is a good place to start http://jqueryfundamentals.com. Then check here on how to ask good questions http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Answer (score 0):

Get your URL / Parse it:

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
```

Then add the class:

Jquery:

```
$(element).addClass('classname');
```

JS: [How do I add a class to a given element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507138/how-do-i-add-a-class-to-a-given-element)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var url = location.href;
    $('#navigation li a').each(function () {
        var thisHref = this.getAttribute('href');
        if (thisHref !== '#' && url.indexOf(thisHref) !== -1) {
            $(this.parentNode).addClass('active');
            return;
        }
    });
});
```