# How to toggle by className inside div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to toggle a popup when DIV is clicked. There is multiple DIV's that can be clicked and one popup each inside them.

So far what I have tried:

```
<div class="popup">Button1
   <span class="myPopup">Text inside popup</span>
</div>
<div class="popup">Button2
   <span class="myPopup">Text inside popup</span>
</div>

<script>
var el = document.querySelectorAll(".popup");
for(var i =0; i < el.length; i++) {
   el[i].onclick = function() { document.getElementsByClassName('myPopup')[i].classList.toggle("show")};
}
</script>
```

There will always be one popup inside one div, so I assumed if there is click event on div I can get element by class name (myPopup) and use same index to open myPopup, but I can't get it to work. Would like to get this done preferably only using JavaScript.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass arguments to addEventListener listener function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256754/how-to-pass-arguments-to-addeventlistener-listener-function)

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075104/how-to-toggle-switch-class-of-a-div-onclick-using-only-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using

`document.getElementsByClassName('myPopup')[i]`

use

`this.querySelector('.myPopup')`

`this` refers to `el` so the query happens only inside of each `el`.

Instead of `getElementsByClassName('myPopup')[i]` we use `querySelector('.myPopup')` which always returns the first `.mypopup` within each `el`.

(Edited after good feedback provided by @[Heretic Monkey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/215552/heretic-monkey))

```js
var el = document.querySelectorAll(".popup");
for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
  el[i].onclick = function() {
    this.querySelector('.myPopup').classList.toggle("show");
  }
}
```

```css
.myPopup {
  display: none;
}

.myPopup.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="popup">Button1
  <span class="myPopup">Text inside popup1</span>
</div>
<div class="popup">Button2
  <span class="myPopup">Text inside popup2</span>
</div>
```

Comment: @HereticMonkey You're right of course. Thanks, I edited my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

This is a working example:

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".popup")
elements.forEach(el => {
  el.onclick = function(event) {
    this.classList.toggle("show")
  }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Buntel/8smdh5ou/9/

Seems you had an typo in classList.**toggle**()