# How do you set a css class attribute with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The element i'm working with is a image i would like displayed during load time.

I am trying to set a css class attribute, i can set attributes on my image but its class attributes override's it.

So i need to set the class attribute. The class is .bgImage

This is how i set the attribute:

```
LoadingImg.setAttribute("display", "block");
```

---

This is what i have tried:

```
LoadingImg.className("display", "block");
```

And

```
LoadingImg.setAttribute(".bgImage display", "block");
```

---

CSS:

```
.bgImage {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; left: 33%;
  right: 0; bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Exstra info:

LoadingImg is the image object, i had to grab it through iFrame levels.

```
var HomeDoc = $('#ContentFrame').contents()[0];
var LoadingImg = HomeDoc.all.namedItem('LoadingImg');
```

Comment: check [here][1]

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507138/how-do-i-add-a-class-to-a-given-element


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507138/how-do-i-add-a-class-to-a-given-element

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the style property to set the style in javascript.

```
LoadingImg.style.display = "block";
```

Comment: Thanks this has worked :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use jQuery you can try:

```
$( "#LoadingImg" ).css( "display","block" );
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use jQuery `LoadingImg.addClass( ".bgImage" ).css("display", "block");`
or
`LoadingImg.attr("class", ".bgImage").css("display", "block");`