# selector.addClass('classname') in pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html

in jQuery you can do this:

```
$('#myElement').addClass('header');
```

how can I make it like this in pure javascript

```
var elem = document.getElementById('myElement');
elem.addClass('header');
```

So I want to make a small custom library which use the selector before the function instead of this:

```
function addClass(element, class) {
    element.className += ' ' + class;
}
```

which is called like this:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('myElement');
addClass(elem, 'header');
```

Is this possible and if it is how can I do that?

Comment: Why not just use jQuery instead of reinventing the wheel?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I add a class to a given element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507138/how-do-i-add-a-class-to-a-given-element)

Comment: FWIW, you can do exactly what you've proposed, except that you shouldn't use a variable named `class` because it's a reserved word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own `addClass` method, something like:

```
function addClass(element, classname){
    var currentClassList = (element.className || '').split(/\s+/);
    currentClassList
     .push(currentClassList.indexOf(classname) > -1 ? '' : classname);
    element.className = currentClassList.join(' ').trim();
}
```

Here's a [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/b7x7qpf4/) demo using this function

`/*Note*/` A polyfill for `Array.indexOf` can be found [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)
`/*Note 2*/` A polyfill for `String.trim` can be found [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)

Comment: @Downvoter: not that I care much about the downvote, but I'd like to learn about your motive for it.

Comment: It doesn't work, gives error "Can't find variable: className on line 3", can you please look at that?

Comment: other error now: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'currentClassList.push(classname).join(' ')')

Comment: The function was a bit sloppy, sorry. It's corrected now. I'll add a jsFiddle demo

Answer (score 6):

In HTML5 browsers, you can do this:

```
elem.classList.add('header');
```

I'd strongly suggest coding to modern standards wherever possible and [use a shim](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills) to support older browsers as required.  Eventually you'll be able to decommission the shims and you won't end up left with a load of crufty inefficient old code that was only written that way because of the old browsers.

Comment: I know but why I should write my code double for browsers which allow classList? I mean I also have to write code for non html5 browsers

Comment: You don't have to write double code - there's plenty of shims already written.  The point is that developers should use modern APIs whenever available and monkey patch the older browsers that don't have them.  On newer browsers the modern code will just run natively and on older browsers the same code still works.  See the link in my answer for more context.