# How to change an HTML element's class using it's id attribute

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I've the following HTML:

```
<li class="treeview" id="account_management">
```

So I want to target the element with `id` "account_management" and change it's class from "treeview" to "treeview active", so that I can then style my tree menu accordingly.

Comment: It's well worth your time to spend an hour or two reading through [the jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com). It really only takes that long, and it answers this question and hundreds more.

Comment: thanks @T.J.Crowder surely you can answer every single question on this site by saying read the docs? Not really helpful. I don't have any intention of learning jQuery at this moment in time as I don't really have any need for it other than this right now. There's no point in my writing poor code if someone who knows the mechanics of the language that is will to spend a minute to help me

Comment: The point is that if you will learn the very basic jQuery things, it will save your and other people time. Noone said that you should learn it completely.

Comment: @twigg: It wasn't an answer. It was a suggestion to help save your time and others'. And no, reading the API docs *doesn't* answer every question. Some questions are bigger than API calls. Some are actually about hard things. This is *trivial*, and a trivial glance at the API docs would show you this tempting `addClass` function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I add a class to a given element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507138/how-do-i-add-a-class-to-a-given-element)

Comment: @PhilippM: No, because that question doesn't reference jQuery.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder If the OP isn't interested in learning, next time suggest [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+add+a+class+using+jquery&oq=how+to+add+a+class+using+jquery&aqs=chrome..69i57.7084j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)  ;)

Answer (score 5):

You can use jQuery [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) to add the class `active`:

```
$("#account_management").addClass("active");
```

---

Or you can use [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList) DOM API's `add()` method like:

```
document.getElementById("account_management").classList.add("active");
```

classList browser support @[caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist)

for older versions, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26157172/2333214).

Comment: Yes, it is always sad when big work stays even without "accepted". By the way, mentioned answer was posted after 2.5 months - it was probably too late, even though it works correctly :)

Answer (score 1):

In pure JavaScript you could do:

```
var d = document.getElementById("account_management");
d.className = d.className + " active";
```

*If you already use jQuery in your project, I would recommend to make use of it like in T J's answer.*

Comment: Using jQuery or not using jQuery has no relation to the language you're using (JavaScript). You mean "Using the DOM you could do:"

Comment: I know that jQuery is also JavaScript. By `pure JavaScript` I meant, without a framework.

Comment: @Regent: It's just this horrible, and anti-constructive, meme that somehow jQuery is something other than JavaScript. Again, `$("#account_management").addClass("active")` ***is*** "pure JavaScript" (using jQuery). The alternative above is pure JavaScript (using the DOM). Nothing whatsoever to do with the language.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder well, the idea is that "pure JS" is "using JS without additional libraries/plugins". It's just the way how you interpret word "pure".

Comment: @Regent: No, it's the way you interpret the word *JavaScript*, which has no place in that term. Pure DOM is what people actually mean. I'll stop banging on about it. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you mean that [document.getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById) is DOM document's method (not JavaScript method), which returns DOM [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element)?