# Add CSS style to DOM element via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to toggle the opacity of a DOM element on an event which is attached to a javascript method.  A click on checkbox is what triggers the `completed` method.

The below method is triggered on a click:

```
 completed: function(){
                var task = this.$('.actions');

                console.log(task);

                if(!task.hasClass('toggle')){

                    task.addClass('toggle');
                } else {
                    task.removeClass('toggle');
                }

               }
            }
```

The CSS
     `.toggle{
        opacity: 0.4;
         }`

and the HTML (underscore template, in this case) is

```
        <div class="table table-bordered">
            <div class="actions">
                <input type="checkbox" class='completed'>
                <button type='button' class='delete btn btn-danger btn-xs'> x </button>
                <button type='button' class='edit btn btn-primary btn-xs' id='actions'> edit </button>
                <span style='font-weight:bold' class="word" spellcheck='false'> <%= task %>-</span>
                <span class="definition" spellcheck='false'> <%= description %> </span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

But nothing happens.  How can I addClass to a DOM element via javascript?

Comment: `this.$('.actions');` is not correct. if you want `.actions` _inside_ the current element, use `$('.actions', this);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I add a class to a given element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507138/how-do-i-add-a-class-to-a-given-element)

Answer (score 2):

When you add a class using jQuery, you don't need a prefix `.`:

```
task.addClass('toggle');
```

Furthermore, your function seems slightly off:

You either want to use this, when you want to select `.action` globally

```
var task = $('.actions');
```

or this, if it shall be a childnode of the current `this` object:

```
var task = $( this ).find('.actions');
```

Comment: I want the direct parent of $(this), so find() doesnt make sense.

Comment: @redress So use `$(this).parent()`

Comment: your `var task` declarations dont work, but `this.$('.actions')` does ...?

Comment: $(this).parent() also produces no response

Comment: so how does you complete object look like? There are some structures, that make your code valid

Comment: ive updated my method above, and NOTE: the method is triggered on checkbox being clicked

Comment: what is the actual `this` object, when the function is called

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68833/discussion-between-redress-and-sirko).