# Add a class to an element with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if someone could help me. I'm trying to add `.fancy-btn` to the below using JavaScript.

```
<div class="button transparent_2">
<a class="extra-color-3" href="#">Get a quote</a>
</div>
```

I want `.fancy-btn` class added to the div container, but cant seem to figure out how to achieve is

Thanks

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I add a class to a given element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507138/how-do-i-add-a-class-to-a-given-element)

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `.addClass()`:

```
$(".transparent_2").addClass('fancy-btn')
```

Comment: How do you know OP intends to use jQuery?

Comment: In fairness, OP tagged in jQuery @NickM

Answer (score 0):

Here is a JavaScript only method:

```
var $a = document.getElementsByClassName("transparent_2");
//assuming there is only 1 element (or is the first)
$a[0].className += " fancy-btn";
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/x3Lmo1at/)

Answer (score 0):

see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/507157/3503886

Add a space plus the name of your new class to the `className` property of the element. First, put an `id` on the element so you can easily get a reference.

```
<div id="div1" class="someclass">
    <img ... id="image1" name="image1" />
</div>
```

Then

```
var d = document.getElementById("div1");
d.className = d.className + " otherclass";
```