# Adding a class to the previous and next buttons

Tags: javascript

I have a pagination script, where I need to append classes to the previous and next buttons.

Code for the same as below.

```
document.querySelector('.prev').style.opacity=(turntopage == 1)? "0.1" : "1";
document.querySelector('.next').style.opacity=(turntopage == totalpages)? "0.1" : "1";
```

Currently, on click of previous and next, the visibility is being applied from the above which is rendered as below.

```
<a class="next" href="#next" style="opacity: 0.1;">
<a class="next" href="#next" style="opacity: 1;">
```

I need to make changes to the above so instead of style, I can append the class which should be rendered as below.

```
<a class="next disabled" href="#next">
```

Complete demo can be seen **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/4xvcuz6h/7/)**

Comment: So just do `.classList.add("disabled")` or `.className += " disabled"` instead of that `.style…` thing?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507138/how-do-i-add-a-class-to-a-given-element

Comment: @Bergi - I did add the `.classList.add("disabled")`, but it is showing as disabled on both on page load, but I want them to append like the style that I have mentioned above which gets applied only when that event occurs

Comment: @Bergi - The `.className += " disabled";` gives multiple instances of disabled class on the mark-up and its getting populated numerous times on click of the buttons.

Comment: Which event? The code in your question contains no event handlers.

Comment: @Bergi - I meant onclick of previous and next events. This is a sample code of what happens from the above code. `<a class="prev disabled disabled disabled" href="#prev"> </a>` and this disabled class gets repeated the number of times you press previous or next.

Comment: @NKL: Then use `classList`. However repetitions of a class should have no noticeable effects, so I wouldn't care for that.

Comment: The repetitions are not good in my case, as lot of inheritance is there + does not make the mark-up look good. @Bergi

Comment: Repetitions of CSS class attributes have nothing to do with inheritance. Yes, the markup becomes a bit odd-looking.

Comment: So the point is, adding them like they are getting added fine with my above style code, in which the mark-up too remains neat. So is there a way to add a class where it gets added and removed like the above style code? - @Bergi

Comment: Yes, just use `.classList.add()` and `.classList.remove()` (or `.classList.toggle()`)!

Comment: But `classList.toggle())` does not support older IE? - @Bergi

Comment: No it does not. But `querySelector` doesn't either, so it didn't look like you would care. You can shim both, though.

Comment: I resolved it on my onw. My answer as below - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30318044/adding-a-class-to-the-previous-and-next-buttons/30319188#30319188 - @Bergi

Answer (score 0):

You can use the classList property with the .add and .remove functions:

document.querySelector('.next').classList.add('disabled');

Comment: I resolved it on my onw. My answer as below - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30318044/adding-a-class-to-the-previous-and-next-buttons/30319188#30319188

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the support. I solved it myself.
I created an `ID` and added it the same way I had style. It resolved my purpose. 
Initially, as per suggestions of the people, I did try `.classList.add`, `.addClass`,  `.className +=`, etc., but that created multiple instances/duplication of the classes on click of previous and next and that made the mark-up look very messy. This works smoothly. Let me know for any suggestions/edits.

Changes in the code as below.

```
document.querySelector('.prev').id=(turntopage == 1)? "disabled" : "enabled";
document.querySelector('.next').id=(turntopage == totalpages)? "disabled" : "enabled";
```

**[LIVE DEMO OF THE SOLUTION](http://jsfiddle.net/4xvcuz6h/12/)**

Comment: `classList` doesn't duplicate class names?

Comment: It does the duplication. When you check the mark-up on inspect, you can see that. - @Bergi

Comment: Using ids is very messy. There can be multiple `disabled` and `enabled` elements on a page, yet ids must be unique. Your script doesn't work fine if both elements are enabled, if there are multiple paginated contents in the document, or when there are zero pages so both elements are disabled.

Comment: Better make `#next` and `#prev` become ids and use `enabled`/`disabled` classes that you can assign (and overwrite) using `className`.

Comment: No it works fine. You can check the demo. It only shows disabled for the first previous and the last next. Rest all are enabled. So it remains unique. Plus, the things you have mentioned above does not replicate in my scenario. Thanks for your suggestions. Shall take a note of it - @Bergi

Comment: I cannot confirm the duplication. What browser are you using? According to the HTML5 spec there must be no duplicate items in a classlist.

Comment: "*Rest all are enabled*" doesn't sound very unique :-)

Comment: `#next` and `#prev` as Id's is a good idea. But I have already them on lot of pages. So changing cannot be ideal now. I can take this note and create it for future implementations. - @Bergi

Comment: My correction - I mean previous and next and not all as enabled - @Bergi

Answer (score -1):

Either I don't get it, or I don't know what to think...

$( "a" ).addClass( "addClass1 addClass2" );

change the first part to change how the tag matching is done (by element, by id, etc)..
but this seems too easy, so most likely i'm missing the point...

upd: missed the no jquery.. use plain js..
var d = document.getElementById("a");
d.className = d.className + " disabled";

Comment: There's no jQuery in the question.

Comment: seems fair.. use this:
var d = document.getElementById("a");
d.className = d.className + " disabled";

Comment: I resolved it on my onw. My answer as below - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30318044/adding-a-class-to-the-previous-and-next-buttons/30319188#30319188