# Multiple classes

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to add a second class to an HTML tag using javascript? For example, say you had the element `<p class="a">` and you wanted to add class="b". If you used `document.getElementByClassName("a").class = "b"` that would remove class "a". Is there a way to have both in the same element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementsByClassName("a")[0].className += " b"
```

First of all, the method is named `getElementsByClassName`, plural. You need to refer to a specific element in the collection that it returns, via a zero-based index.

And you need the space before `b` here, so that you don’t end up with `ab`, but `a b`.

Comment: You need to use `className`, not `class`

Comment: @bumpy: You’re right of course, don’t know how I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one here:

```
document.getElementByClassName("a").className += " b"
```

Got it from here: [How do I add a class to a given element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507138/how-do-i-add-a-class-to-a-given-element)

Comment: You need to use `className`, not `class`

Comment: Damn copy paste. :) Thanks for the hint. fixed