# How to append one more class to exisiting one in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, classname

I want to bind a class to tr using jQuery. tr looks as below:

```
<tr id="@item[1]">
    <td>@item[0]</td>
    <td>@item[1]</td>
</tr>
```

after loading the data above tr looks as below:

```
<tr class="even" id="1">
    <td>AAA</td>
    <td>BBB</td>
</tr>
```

here i want to add one more class "read_only" to my tr as below:

```
<tr class="read_only even" id="1">
    <td>AAA</td>
    <td>BBB</td>
</tr>
```

how to do this in jQuery?

Comment: `$(".even").addClass("read_only")` ??

Comment: A VERY simple search with google was more than enought. Go google, type "jquery add class to element" and click the first result

Comment: `<tr class="read_only @item[1]">` ?

Comment: I know it is simple and direct one but in my case class "even" is add to the tr on run time. so my question is how to add one more class dynamically. In design i know only the id of each tr.

Comment: What have you tried? What do you mean the even class is added on "run time"? Why is the ID of any importance?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a class to a given element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507138/how-do-i-add-a-class-to-a-given-element)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".even").addClass("read_only")
```