# Bootstrap - How to add <select class="form-control"> dynamically in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, select

I'm learning Bootstrap and jQuery. I'm very new to both of them.

I would like to generate the tag `<select class="form-control">`
dynamically through JavaScript code.

I have the following code in my JavaScript:

```
var response = originalRequest.responseXML;
var property = document.createElement("select");
property.id = "predicate(" + addprop.level + "," + addprop.count + ")";
property[property.length] = new Option("Properties", "");
var options = response.getElementsByTagName('option');
```

From what I've read, the `document.createElement("select")` creates the select tag dynamically.

My question is, how do I make that dynamically generated select tag using Bootstrap style (i.e. using `class="form-control"`)?

I want the dropdown to be generated dynamically through jQuery/JavaScript (i.e., without using the `select` tag in the HTML/JSP file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a class to a given element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507138/how-do-i-add-a-class-to-a-given-element)

Comment: Not quite the same question.  In this case OP could / should add the class while building it.

Comment: @filoxo Thank you! I didn't realize a question was already asked like mine. Can you post your comment as an 'answer'? I will check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
property.className = "form-control";
```

Full:

```
var response = originalRequest.responseXML;
var property = document.createElement("select");
property.className = "form-control";
property.id = "predicate(" + addprop.level + "," + addprop.count + ")";
property[property.length] = new Option("Properties", "");
var options = response.getElementsByTagName('option');
```

More info on MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $('element') to create any document element
then use the .append(element) to put the element to the target parent... Try my code if it works

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form role="form">
    <div class="form-group" id="div">

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```

```
      <label>Select</label>
    </div>
  </form>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var select = $('<select class="form-control"></select>');
    var option = $('<option value="foo">Foo</option');
    select.append(option);
    $("#div").append(select);
  }); 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey thank you for the answer! But another user already answered my question. So I had to "check" his answer as the correct one. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Generally i create new things like 
https://jsfiddle.net/Ljdxnwot/5/
i write such as text

```
var txt="<select class'form-contro'>"+
"</select>";
```

Comment: Hey thank you for the answer! But another user already answered my question. So I had to "check" his answer as the correct one. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $('element') to create any document element
then use the .append(element) to put the element to the target parent... Try my code if it works

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form role="form">
    <div class="form-group" id="div">
      <label>Select</label>
    </div>
  </form>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var select = $('<select class="form-control"></select>');
    var option = $('<option value="foo">Foo</option>');
    select.append(option);
    $("#div").append(select);
  }); 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
      <label>Select</label>
    </div>
  </form>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var select = $('<select class="form-control"></select>');
    var option = $('<option value="foo">Foo</option');
    select.append(option);
    $("#div").append(select);
  }); 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```