# Add class in body tag when change language in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, lang

My HTML tag is this `<html lang="en-US">`, When I change language from English to Danish lang tag changed to this `<html lang="da-DK">`.

**Problem:** I want to add a class `class="xyz"` when my selected language is `<html lang="da-DK">`.
Any possible solution to add a class using javascript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a class to a given element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507138/how-do-i-add-a-class-to-a-given-element)

Comment: you are changing class in some button click?

Answer (score 0):

simply use Jquery :lang() Selector

for example

`if($( "html:lang(en-US)" )){
   $("body").addClass( "usa" )
}`

Not tested but hopefully work, 
see [Here](https://api.jquery.com/lang-selector/) for more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

1. CSS `:lang` selector.[More](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:lang) about css lang selector
2. `$( ":lang(your language)").addClass/removeClass('className')`;

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
if(document.documentElement.getAttribute('lang')=='da-DK'){
   document.body.className = ' xyz';
}
```

Comment: will it able to detect the change?

Comment: This need to be triggered in that event.

Comment: It is adding class in html tag, but I want to add class in body tag

Comment: Then do document.body.classname. Check updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it will work :**

```
if ($('html').attr('lang') == 'da-DK') {
     $('html').addClass("xyz");
}
```

Comment: OP has not tagged the question as jQuery.