# How to insert Node based on css class in JS?

Tags: javascript

I have this code that highlights the text selection. It wraps the text that was selected within a passage and then adds `<span style='background:yellow'> text selected </span>` I want to accomplish the exact same task, but instead, do this:

```
<span class='blue_mark'> text selected </span>
```

How can I accomplish this within the following code:

```
var selection = document.getSelection();
  var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
  var contents = range.extractContents();
  var node = document.createElement('span');
  node.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
  node.appendChild(contents);
  range.insertNode(node);
  selection.removeAllRanges(); //Clear the selection, showing highlight
```

Comment: No, how do you use addClass() with insertNode? I know how to use it in other causes: `$("#id").addClass("example");`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507138/how-do-i-add-a-class-to-a-given-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want a class instead of a style attribute, use this by replacing `node.style. backgroundColor = "yellow";` with `node.classList.add('blue_mark');` or `node.className += ' blue_mark';`.

Comment: Don't forget the space: `node.className += ' blue_mark';`