# How to call another class on hover in CSS?

Tags: html, css

The class of DIV is FIRST. I want to call class SECOND on hover. How can I do this?

I am using following code:

```css
.first{
background:#F00;
}
.second{
background: #0F0;
}
```

```html
<div class="first"> This is DIV</div>
```

Comment: there is no `second` element in the code above?

Comment: You can't *"call a class"* in CSS...it's not a programming language. It's a ruleset.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use an additional class, just add the additional style on hover using the pseudo-selector :hover

```
<style>
.first{
background:#F00;
}
.first:hover{
background: #0F0;
}
</style>
```

As i am very kind, i have added an example of how to do what you are asking in pure javascript also:

```
<style>
.first{
background:#F00;
}
.second{
background: #0F0;
}
</style>

<div class="first" onmouseover="change()" onmouseout="changeBack()"> This is DIV</div>
<script>
function change() {
    var d = document.getElementsByClassName("first");
    d[0].className += " second";
}
function changeBack() {
    var d = document.getElementsByClassName("first");
    d[0].className = "first";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi.. I want to call another class on hover

Comment: you can only call another class on hover using javascript, not css

Comment: Hi Hairmot.. how can i do it..please assist

Comment: so you will need to write some javascript to detect the hover. See this w3 schools page: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp

Comment: then you need to add the class, also using javascript. see the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/507157/3759705

Comment: It isn't possible in all cases but it isn't impossible either: `:hover + .class` is fine for example

Answer (score 2):

Your above way is not correct to do what you are looking for.
Check the below to know how to do it.

**[Live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/h10auxrh/)**

**The HTML code:**

```
<div class="first"> This is DIV</div>
```

**The CSS Code:**

```
.first{
background:#F00;
}
.first:hover{
background: #0F0;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

**Explanation**

You need to declare `:hover` to create hover effect. So instead of creating a new class, you need to add `:hover` i.e a pseudo class to the class where you want the `hover` to work. This will make the hover effect you are looking for.

**Reference:**
[W3 Hover reference](https://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/Test/CSS3/Selectors/current/html/full/flat/css3-modsel-18.html)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can style an element (with a certain class) when another one is hovered in a limited number of cases. Main constraint: the hovered element must be placed in HTML code *before* the styled one.

More about `+` and `~` the [adjacent and general sibling combinators](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#sibling-combinators)

```css
.first{
background:#F00;
}
.second{
background-color: #0F0;
}
.first:hover ~ .second {
  background-color: tomato;
}
.first:hover ~ .hello .second {
  background-color: violet;
}
.hello {
  background-color: beige;
}
.hello {
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="first"> This is DIV</div>
<div> Some div</div>
<div class="second"> I've class .second</div>
<div class="hello">
  <div class="second"> Child of a (following) sibling of .first</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hover the first box to see the result

This is how you would do it in javascript.

document.getElementById('idOfElement') is getting element reference.

Adding an event on it. In your case, you need two events which is onmouseover and onmouseleave.

```js
let first = document.getElementById('first'),
    sec = document.getElementById('second');

first.onmouseover = () => {
  sec.style.background = 'black';  
}

first.onmouseleave = () => {
  sec.style.background = 'red';  
}
```

```css
#first, #second {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
```

```html
<div id="first">first</div>
<div id="second">second</div>
```

You can also do this on css. However, this is limited. You can't get reference to your parent element and previous sibling elements. That's what I know. (correct me if I am wrong).

```css
#first, #second {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

#first:hover ~ #second {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="first">first</div>
<div id="second">second</div>
```

Hope it helps. Cheers