# How to add class attribute to a li tag by using Dom

Tags: javascript, dom

I have to add a class attribute to a li tag using DOM. And I'm very lost at it.
This is what I've done, is it correct?

```js
var d = document;
var ul = d.getElementsByTagName('ul');
var li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) 
{
  var clases = d.createElement('class');
  clases.class = 'Bebida';
  li.appendChild(clases);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Café</li>
  <li>Mate</li>
  <li>Té</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How do I add a class to a given element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507138/how-do-i-add-a-class-to-a-given-element)

Comment: See [element.className on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className)

Comment: There is no `<class>`, `class` in this context is an attribute. An attribute is a "setting" of an element (i.e. `id=`, `class=`, `style=`, `height=` `disabled` `contenteditable`, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your Javascript you have a few issues.

First off

```
var ul = d.getElementsByTagName('ul');
```

This returns an array of `ul` elements therefore you cannot call `var li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li')` directly on the array.

You will need to iterate each `ul` in the array and get the `li`'s from the array item such as.

```
var ul = d.getElementsByTagName('ul');
for (var u = 0; u < ul.length; u++) {
  var li = ul[u].getElementsByTagName('li')
}
```

Now just as the `ul` variable the `li` is also an array so you will need to iterate each `li` item in the array.

```
var ul = d.getElementsByTagName('ul');
for (var u = 0; u < ul.length; u++) {
  var li = ul[u].getElementsByTagName('li')
  for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {

  }
}
```

The next problem is you dont create a `class` element. `class` is an attribute of the `li` element. This can be accessed via the `className` property on each element.

To make this work you can put it all together as.

```
var ul = d.getElementsByTagName('ul');
for (var u = 0; u < ul.length; u++) {
  var li = ul[u].getElementsByTagName('li')
  for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    li[i].className = 'Bebida';
  }
}
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e9wtgcx0/) for your review.

I must add one more point. The first loop of capturing the `ul` elements is irrelavant. You could skip this directly and capture all the `li` elements. This will reduce the amount of loops required.

Given that you are capturing all the `ul` elements and then capturing all the `li` for that `ul` you can simply get all the `li` elements from the document. This of course is only the case if you only want the `li` that are children of `ul`s and not other elements (such as `ol`).

This can be reduced to.

```
var liArray = d.getElementsByTagName('li');
for(var i=0; i<liArray.length;i++)
    liArray[i].className = 'Bebida';
```

Comment: Super helpful and very well explained, thank you very much Nico !

Comment: What if i want to add 3 different class to each li ?

Comment: You can seperate the class names with a space or use the `.classList` property. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList