# Is it possible to append a class to existing div dynamically in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, class, dynamic, append, prepend

I am using the Wordpress theme Avada and I want to append a class to a pagination `<div>`.  Currently it is like:

`<div class="pagination clearfix">` and I would like to dynamically be able to add a class to this div like so: `<div class="wp-pagenavi pagination clearfix">`

Is there a way of doing this?  I have searched the theme and cannot find where this `<div>` is so that's the reason for wanting to change it hopefully somehow dynamically.  I hope it makes sense.
Thanks for any help in advance,

Peter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a class to a given element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507138/how-do-i-add-a-class-to-a-given-element)

Answer (score 1):

you can do it using javascript, idk about wordpress and if u can get access to the code, but with javascript you can do the following:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
document.querySelector('.pagination').classList.add('wp-pagenavi');
console.log(document.querySelector('div'));
});
```

```html
<div class="pagination clearfix">
```

**DOMContentLoaded**

DOMContentLoaded wait until the Dom is ready and after execute the srcipt

Comment: Hi, I see that that script works here very well.  However on my page in the console it give me this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null

Comment: do you have another divs or elements with the same class?

Comment: No.  This is how it is when I view the source page:  <div class='pagination clearfix'>  There are no others

Comment: i've edited the code, try again, and if that not work i still have a third option

Comment: No go.  Same error at this line: document.querySelector('.pagination').classList.add('wp-pagenavi');

Comment: are you executing your script from console? or are you adding the script to your wp page?

Comment: I tried using this: var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("pagination clearfix");
elements[0].className += " wp-pagenavi"; and got an error also : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined

Comment: I am adding the script in the header of my wp page

Comment: not, you need to add the script in the bottom of your page, before close body tag, but if you want have the script in the header i will show you the 3rd option

Comment: Ok, one second and will add before closing body tag

Comment: not problem brother, i've edited the code, so you can too put the script in your head tag