# Slide show add and remove class for change image and button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want make slide show.
its my code:
java script =>

```js
setInterval(function () {
  var activeLi = document.querySelector('li.current');
 activeLi.classList.remove('current');
 if (activeLi.nextElementSibling ) {
  activeLi.nextElementSibling .classList.add('current');
 } else {
  activeLi.parentElement.firstElementChild.classList.add('current')
 }
 var activeIMG = document.querySelector('.active_slider');
 activeIMG.classList.remove('active_slider');
 if (activeIMG.nextElementSibling ) {
  activeIMG.nextElementSibling .classList.add('active_slider');
 } else {
  activeIMG.parentElement.firstElementChild.classList.add('active_slider')
 }
}, 5000);
```

```css
.active_slider{
  display: inline;
 }
 .current{
  color: red;
 }
```

```html
<div id="slider" class="dk-box mrg-bottom">
    <div id="dk-slider-div" class="slides center">
        <a class="clickCount" elementtype="1" categorytitle="">
            <img src="/f15468d9.jpg" class="slideItem active_slider">
        </a>
        <a class="clickCount" elementtype="1" categorytitle="">
            <img src="/f15468d9.jpg" class="slideItem">
        </a>
        <a class="clickCount" elementtype="1" categorytitle="">
            <img src="/f15468d9.jpg" class="slideItem">
        </a>
        <footer>
            <ul class="tabs">
                <li class="tabItem current">
                    <a>
                        Slide 1
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="tabItem">
                    <a>
                        Slide 2
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="tabItem">
                    <a>
                        Slide 3
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

buttons was active and changed after 5 sec but image doesn't change
`active_slider` = active slider
`current` = active button
how can i make auto change for slider
i want add class for active and remove class for hide
if cant with class i can active with style { display: inline; }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a class to a given element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507138/how-do-i-add-a-class-to-a-given-element)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! 
Have you tried anything so far? 
StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to 
[try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). 
Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a 
[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
For further information, please see 
[how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
and take the 
[tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: google #1: javascript how to add class. google #2: javascript timeout

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, it will run every 3 second and set the class active to the next element.

```js
setInterval(function(){ 
  var slider = $(".slider");
  var active = slider.find(".active");
  var sliderCount = slider.find("li").length;
  var index = active.index();
  
  active.removeClass("active");
  
  if (index < sliderCount - 1){
    active.next().addClass("active")
  } else {
    slider.find("li:first").addClass("active")
  }
  
}, 3000);
```

```css
.active{
  color: yellow
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
    <li class="slide1">
        <img src"image.png" alt="1">
    </li>
    <li class="slide2 active">
        <img src"image.png" alt="2">
    </li>
    <li class="slide3">
        <img src"image.png" alt="3">
    </li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your html is invalid, there is `=` missing after `class`, should be `class="slide1 active"`. To invoke function after some time you can use [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) adn to modify classes you can modify [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)
property:

```js
var x = 1000;

setInterval(function () {
  var activeLi = document.querySelector('li.active');
  activeLi.classList.remove('active');
  if (activeLi.nextElementSibling ) {
    activeLi.nextElementSibling .classList.add('active');
  } else {
    activeLi.parentElement.firstElementChild.classList.add('active')
  }
}, x);
```

```css
.active {
  color:red
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
    <li class="slide1 active">
        <img src"image.png">
    </li>
    <li class="slide2">
        <img src"image.png">
    </li>
    <li class="slide3">
        <img src"image.png">
    </li>
</div>
```

On every interval it removes class `active` from element and checks if element has sibling element (by checking `nextElementSibling` existence). Depending on it, `active` class is attached to either sibling or first element (`parentElement.firstElementChild`).

Comment: how automatic for all slides? slide1 and slide2 and slide3 and again

Comment: if my code doesn't have <li> tag how find it in document.querySelector ? for example : document.querySelector('img.active');

Comment: document.querySelector('img.active') should work as well as document.querySelector('.active')

Comment: i changed my text and code and ... can you help me?