# Add class to button inside a js function

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, dynamic

I want to create buttons and add classes to those button after creation
I am working on below code !1 Please Help me out :)

Will this work?

```
$("#"+element.id).addClass(".btn");
```

Thank you in advance !!

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
  add(i);
}

function add(i) {

  var element = document.createElement("input");

  element.type = "button";
  element.value = i;
  element.name = i + 1;
  element.id = "btn" + i;
  element.onclick = function() {
    window.move(i);
  };

  var append = document.getElementById("append");

  append.appendChild(element);
  alert(element.id);
  $("#" + element.id).addClass(".btn");
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a class to a given element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507138/how-do-i-add-a-class-to-a-given-element)

Comment: when using `.addClass()` you can omit the `.` in front of the classname

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add classes in javascript like that:

```
element.className += 'className';
```

If you are using jQuery then what you did is correct, except the dot you put into addClass function. So instead of:

```
$(element).addClass('.className');
```

You do:

```
$(element).addClass('className');
```

Comment: Thank you so much, It Worked :)

Answer (score 2):

You can add class directly by accessing "className" property.

```
var element = document.createElement("input");

element.type = "button";
element.className = "clr-red";
```

[Refer here for more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use without dot.

> $("#"+element.id).addClass("btn");

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the classList.add method on the element you create.

```
   for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        add(i);
    }
    function add(i) {

        var element = document.createElement("input");

        element.type = "button";
        element.value = i; 
        element.name = i + 1;
        element.id="btn"+i;
        element.classList.add("btn");
        element.onclick = function () { 
            window.move(i);




        };


        var append =document.getElementById("append");
        append.appendChild(element);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you just type the class name only

```
addClass("btn"); instead of addClass(".btn");
```