# How can a class be added to a div with an id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I two pages home.html and service.html. On the home page when this link `a href="services#v-pills-manpower"` is clicked on, I want to add `show active` class to the div on the service page with the id `#v-pills-manpower`.

This is the html in my service.html

```
<div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-services"></div>

<div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-manpower"></div>
```

This is the javascript

```
var hash = document.location.hash;
var pills = document.querySelectorAll('*[id]');

if($.inArray(hash, pills)) {
    // console.log(hash + 'is in IDs array');
    // Add show active class to the div with the hash id
}
```

How can i achieve my goal?

Comment: You can use `document.querySelector(location.hash)` to get the element that has that ID (if any).

Comment: Which library provides your `$`? Please tag it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a class to a given element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507138/how-do-i-add-a-class-to-a-given-element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `classList` to add, remove, or toggle classes:

```
// single item
document.getElementById('some-id').classList.add('show')

// multiple items
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('*[id]')

for (let i of elements) {
    elements[i].classList.add('show')
}
```

For your example use the hash as the selector:

```
let sel = document.location.hash.substr(1)
document.getElementById(sel).classList.add('show')
```

edit: if you're going to downvote at least have the courtesy to give an explanation as to why.

Comment: I'm getting the error `Cannot read property 'classList' of null`

Comment: That means your selector is wrong. I've updated with a possible a fix

Comment: I'm able to see the div when i `console.log(sel)` but I still get the same error when i try to add the class, stiil think the selector is wrong?

Comment: `document.location.hash` starts with `#`. You should use something like `let sel = location.hash.substr(1)`.

Comment: I'm obviously doing something wrong as the error won't go away. Is it possible that not removing the active class `show active` class from the first div could cause the error? I basically using your code and still get the error

Comment: Try this: in the web inspector console enter `document.getElementById("v-pills-manpower")`. Does it find the element you expect?

Comment: @Mena You're probably trying to access that element before it is added to the DOM. Make sure the page is completely loaded before your code is executed.

Comment: I was getting the error because my link was wrong `services#manpower` instead of `services#v-pills-manpower`. Now it failing to execute because i'm trying to add 2 classes like this `show active` so it's complaining about the space in between. How can i add more than one class in one statement?

Comment: separate the classes with commas like `div.classList.add("foo", "bar");`

Comment: That was the miracle i needed.

Comment: I didn't downvote, so I can't advise on why anyone may have done that. But it is worth noting that OP is already using jQuery, so a jQuery solution will often result in simpler code than the direct DOM operations. For example if you did need to select multiple elements and add a class to each, you could do that without any loop at all. The code would be the same as I posted for a single element selected with `location.hash`, just using a different selector.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the answer here [Change an element's class with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-class-with-javascript)

> To add an additional class to an element: To add a class to an
>   element, without removing/affecting existing values, append a space
>   and the new classname, like so:
>
> `document.getElementById("MyElement").className += " MyClass";`

In your case, it should be:

```
document.getElementById("v-pills-manpower").className += " show active";
```

If you are using Bootstrap, the default class for showing a tab / pill should be: `fade in active`.

Comment: Yes I'm working with bootstrap but I'm also getting the error `Cannot read property 'className' of null`

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery, you can easily do this with one simple line of code:

```
$(location.hash).addClass( 'show active' );
```

You don't need to create an array of elements and search it, because what you're matching on is the element `id`. `location.hash` happens to be in the format for a jQuery `id` selector: `"#the-id"`, so you can use it directly.

So `$(location.hash)` gives you a jQuery object with your element in it. Then [`.addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) adds the classes. You can also use [`.removeClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) to remove classes.