# How to add and remove active class using js

Tags: javascript

This is my menu html How can i add active class and remove active class using js :

```
<div class="sidenav">
    <a  href="{{url('/home')}}" class="sidemenu"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> 
    </br>Users</a>
    <a href="{{route('user-channel.index')}}" class="sidemenu"><i class="fa 
    fa-plus"></i></br>Channel</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This should help > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507138/how-do-i-add-a-class-to-a-given-element .

Scroll down in the same page, you should see answers for removing class as well.

Comment: What language/template engine/framework is that?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work.

```js
var sideNav = document.querySelector(".sidenav");
sideNav.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();

  if (e.target.classList.contains("sidemenu")) {
    for (let i = 0; i <= sideNav.children.length - 1; i++) {
      if (sideNav.children[i].classList.contains("active")) {
        sideNav.children[i].classList.remove("active");
      }
    }
    e.target.classList.add("active");
  }
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: blue;
  background-color: yellow;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidenav">
  <a href="" class="sidemenu"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>
   </br>Users</a>
  <a href="" class="sidemenu"><i class="fa 
     fa-plus"></i></br>Channel</a>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be better if you add HTML markup in the code snippet!

Answer (score 0):

In short, use something like this:

```
// Get element
var element = document.getElementById("sidenav");

// Add class
element.classList.add("active");

// Remove class
element.classList.remove("active");
```

Follow up [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_add_class.asp) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

this how you can do it.

```
const linkList = document.querySelectorAll('.sidemenu');
const link = document.querySelector('.sidemenu');

link.addEventListener('click', e => {
  let $this = e.target;
  linkList.forEach(ele => {
    ele.classList.remove('active');
  });
  $this.classList.add('active');
});
```

javascript interpreter in browser read script from top to bottom so first we get the list of items have calss `.sidemenu` by declaring consistent variable `linkList` then we get the one element node by declaring another consistent variable `link` after we make click event inside we declare variable `$this` to refer to the event target (the element i have clicked) then we make loop on all links that have `.sidemenu` class to remove class `active` then out side the loop and in event block we add `active` class to the target (the element i have just clicked)