# Two buttons switch

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that it might have been asked billion times, but I could not find any solutions. So, here is my code:

```css
.btn {
  width: 200px;
  height: 45px;
}

.--selected {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="btn --selected">uno</button>
  <button class="btn">dos</button>
</div>
```

I need to make that after pressing button it added a --selected class to it, and another one lost it, as if it is a switch between two

Help me out, please

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/addclass, http://api.jquery.com/removeclass

Comment: might also check toggleClass

Comment: I'm not sure why you removed your jQuery code from the question? You've made it worse by doing that

Comment: I know how to add class to an element. The question is how to make one lose it after I pressed a different button

Comment: Not complicated ... `$('.btn.--selected').removeClass('--selected')`

Comment: Can you post the code where you attempted to do this please?

Comment: `addClass()` adds, `removeClass()` removes and `toggleClass()` toggles. You can find this all in the documentation. https://api.jquery.com/

Comment: I don't think `--selected` is a valid class name. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/which-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors

Comment: @RobinZigmond I don't think it's invalid as much as its discouraged. _W3C_ recommends that leading `-` characters be reserved for vendor specific CSS such as `-moz` and `-webkit`...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a class to a given element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507138/how-do-i-add-a-class-to-a-given-element)

Comment: @War10ck I wasn't personally too sure (I never use class names that don't start with letters), but according to my brief googling starting with 2 hyphens isn't allowed, eg: https://benfrain.com/when-and-where-you-can-use-numbers-in-id-and-class-names/ On the other hand that link refers to the 2.1 spec, it's possible it's now OK - and even more likely that, even if it's technically not allowed, browsers probably accept it anyway. But that doesn't make it good practice (imo).

Comment: @RobinZigmond Agreed. That's an interesting read too. I hadn't seen that before. Great find! Learn something new everyday.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [`removeClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) and [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/).

**Please Note:** `--selected` is not a valid class name. Double dash (`--`) is used to comment code in CSS. Though you can use like single, triple consecutive dashes, it is good practice to avoid those naming pattern.

```js
$('.btn').click(function(){
  $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
```

```css
.btn {
  width: 200px;
  height: 45px;
}

.selected {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <button class="btn selected">uno</button>
  <button class="btn">dos</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you eliminate the looping by doing `$('.selected').removeClass('selected')`? it may be a little more efficient...

Answer (score 1):

This will add the class to the button clicked and removes the class from all other elements with the class `btn`.

I changed the classname a little to make it a valid css class name too.

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  $('.btn').not(this).removeClass('selected');
});
```

```css
.btn {
  width: 200px;
  height: 45px;
}

.selected {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <button class="btn">uno</button>
  <button class="btn">dos</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
$('.btn').click(function() {
    $('.btn').removeClass('--selected');
    $(this).addClass('--selected');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily using vanilla Javascript and ES6 as below, not need to add extra library:

```js
const btns = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.btn'));

const toggleClass = (e) => {
  for (var el of btns) {
    el.classList.remove('--selected')
  }
  e.currentTarget.classList.add('--selected')
}

for (var el of btns) {
  el.addEventListener('click', toggleClass)
}
```

```css
.btn {
  width: 200px;
  height: 45px;
}

.--selected {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="btn --selected">uno</button>
  <button class="btn">dos</button>
</div>
```

this code might help you.