# Can't change class name on click with Javascript

Tags: javascript

**Objective**

When my button is clicked, I want to add a class name to a **different** element.

My button code:

```
<a href="#" class="elementor-button-link elementor-button elementor-size-lg" role="button" id="explorebuttonid">
```

Class before button is clicked. **This is not the same class as the button**:

```
<div class="elementor-menu-cart__container elementor-lightbox">
```

Desired class after button is clicked. **This is not the same class as the button**:

```
<div class="elementor-menu-cart__container elementor-lightbox elementor-menu-cart--shown">
```

**Problem**

When I try the below, nothing happens when the button is clicked.

**What I have tried**

I have tried implementing these two together:

1) Add a click listener: [Link](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_addeventlistener_displaydate)

2) Insert a function to alter the class name: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507138/how-do-i-add-a-class-to-a-given-element)

```
<script>
document.getElementById("explorebuttonid").addEventListener("click", clicky1);

function clicky1() {
var clicky2 = document.getElementsByClassName("elementor-menu-cart__container elementor-lightbox");

clicky2.className += "elementor-menu-cart--shown";

}
</script>
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` will returns a `HTMLCollection` then you have to iterate every one to apply some effect

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns an ` HTMLCollection` which is similar to an array of HTML elements you have to iterate through the array and apply the class to the elements or you can use `getElementById("explorebuttonid")` and apply the class to the element

Comment: <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button> and then in script function myFunction() {
   var element = document.getElementById("myDIV");
   element.classList.add("mystyle");
}

Comment: @NijeeshJoshy thanks for the feedback. However, I forgot to mention that the class I want to change is separate from the button. Thus, I cannot grab it by ID.

Comment: @Nitintiwari thanks. But I can't amend the HTML code on the page so that wouldn't be possible.