# Change the direction of opening and closing navigation menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a form . in this form when the screen in the mobile size it must use the navigation menu for show detail of form .

my site is multi language . when the language is the `en` it must be `ltr` and open the navigation from `left` page and when the language is `fa` it must be `rtl` open the navigation from `right` .

i write that code but i dont know how change the open direction of navigation . i put my code here please help for solve this problem .

[Demo](https://codepen.io/kianoush/pen/GRpwZJy)

```
<button mat-raised-button onclick="openNav()" id="showInfos" color="primary">
```

Click for Open

```
 <div id="activity-info" class="activity-info">
    <div class="activity-container">
      <div class="activity-header">
        <span id="closeActivityInfo" (click)="closeActivityInfo()">
          <mat-icon>clear</mat-icon>
        </span>
        <div class="activity-info-title">
          <span>
            {{ "GENERAL.ACTIVITY_INFO" | translate }}
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="activity-content">
        <div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="item-label">{{ "GENERAL.CREATOR" | translate }} :</div>
            <div class="item-value">
              <pfa-user-field
                [displayName]="oldEditModel.creator"
                [row]="false"
              ></pfa-user-field>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Css Code :

```
    #showInfos {
    display: block;
    width: 100% !important;
    margin-bottom: 7px !important;
  }
  #closeActivityInfo {
    display: block;
  }
  .activity-info-title {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .activity-info {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
  }
  .activity-container {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .edit-form {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .form-content {
    height: 100%;
  }
  .showInfos {
    width: 60px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #e52727;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    right: 40px;
    bottom: 20px;
  }
}
```

and this is js code :

```
    function openNav(){
   document.getElementById("activity-info").style.width = "80%";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all you have to do to make it open from the right is to remove the `left` property and add `right` property with the same value as in `left` property in `.activity-info` in css, so to open it from the left use the following:

```
  .activity-info {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
  }
```

and to open it from the right use the following:

```
  .activity-info {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    right: 0; // here is the trick
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
  }
```

so what's the solution to not repeat the code over and over again ?
very simple you will have 1 class (main class) and 2 other classes (to open from the right or the left based on the language)

so here is the main class:

```
  .activity-info {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
  }
```

left class:

```
  .activity-info-left {
    left: 0;
  }
```

right class:

```
  .activity-info-right {
    right: 0;
  }
```

and in the html:

```
<div id="activity-info" class="activity-info activity-info-right">
```

you have add the appropriate class to div based on the language. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507138/how-do-i-add-a-class-to-a-given-element)  you can find how to add class to the element.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by changing initial position of div before animation start.

```
function openNav(){
   document.getElementById("activity-info").style.width = "80%";
   if(language === 'fa') { // Assumed variable name language
      document.getElementById("activity-info").style.right = 0;
      document.getElementById("activity-info").style.left = 'auto';
   } else {
      document.getElementById("activity-info").style.left = 0;
  }
}
```