# How to hide a button with .innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to hide a button with .innerHTML?
I tried the following code but it did not work:

```js
function F1() {
  bL1 = document.getElementById("bL1").innerHTML = '<body class="hidden">';
  ebL1 = document.getElementById("ebL1").innerHTML = '</body>';
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="F1()">Hide Lw</button>
<label id="bL1"></label>
<button> Lw </button>
<label id="ebL1"></label>
```

Comment: Why use `innerHTML`? Why not simply [add the `hidden` class to your button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507138/how-do-i-add-a-class-to-a-given-element)?

Comment: To hide the button, you should set the class name of the button to "hidden".

Comment: This is a simplified version of a complex situation, where adding a class directly to the button is not wanted. Adding the class must happen via innerHTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying in this method you are doing very wrong but use the following code that should work correctly to hide a button or anything you want to hide.

```js
function F1() {
  bL1 = document.getElementById("bL1").style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<button onclick="F1()">Hide Lw</button>
<button id="bL1"> Lw </button>
```

This is a very easy and short method to apply CSS inside JavaScript.