# Adding a css class to a html div that is only defined by the combination of css classes it uses with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a website with a few sections that look as following:

```
...
    <div class="row docutils">
        ...
    </div>
...
```

I would like to use javascript to add a custom css class to them so they looks like this:

```
...
    <div class="row docutils my-class">
        ...
    </div>
...
```

I have tried adding a js file in the same directory and added a script reference, however this approach didn't have any effect:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var testarray = document.getElementsByClassName("row docutils");
   for(var i = 0; i < testarray.length; i++)
   {
       testarray[i].className += "my-class";
   }
});
```

Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: `testarray[i].className += "my-class";` won't leave a space between the end of the previous class and the one you're adding. Add a space: `testarray[i].className += " my-class";` or use `classList`: `testarray[i].classList.add("my-class");` or, since you seem to be using jQuery: `$(".row.docutils").addClass("my-class");`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a class to a given element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507138/how-to-add-a-class-to-a-given-element)

Comment: It seems odd to mix different set of api that do the same stuff, ie jQuery (the `$(document).ready(`) and old style vanilla (`document.getElementsByClassName` and `testarray[i].className += "my-class";`). I would rater decide a consistent set for all the DOM related stuff, or at least if I use use jQuery then I use it everywhere otherwise i do not use it at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to prepend a space, since classes are delimited by a space.

```js
var testarray = document.getElementsByClassName("row docutils");
for (var i = 0; i < testarray.length; i++) {
  testarray[i].className += " my-class";
}
```

```css
.my-class {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="row docutils">
  ...
</div>
<div class="row docutils">
  ...
</div>
<div class="row docutils">
  ...
</div>
<div class="row docutils">
  ...
</div>
```

Although you should be using [`classList.add`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/add) instead:

```js
var testarray = document.getElementsByClassName("row docutils");
for (var i = 0; i < testarray.length; i++) {
  testarray[i].classList.add("my-class");
}
```

```css
.my-class {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="row docutils">
  ...
</div>
<div class="row docutils">
  ...
</div>
<div class="row docutils">
  ...
</div>
<div class="row docutils">
  ...
</div>
```

If you want to do it with jQuery:

```js
$('.row.docutils').addClass('my-class');
```

```css
.my-class {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row docutils">
  ...
</div>
<div class="row docutils">
  ...
</div>
<div class="row docutils">
  ...
</div>
<div class="row docutils">
  ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a one expression pure vanilla answer

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.row.docutils')).forEach(
    current => current.classList.add('my-class')
)
```

In most browser you don't even need to cast the `NodeList` returned from `Element.prototype.querySelectorAll` to an array, so you can remove the `Array.from(...)` part, resulting in

```
document.querySelectorAll('.row.docutils').forEach(
    current => current.classList.add('my-class')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using jQuery target the elements with those classes, and use [`addClass`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/).

```js
$('.row.docutils').addClass('red');
```

```css
.red { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row docutils">One</div>
<div class="row">Two</div>
<div class="row docutils">Three</div>
```

Comment: this is a far better answer, considering the question actually has jQuery in it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
      var testarray =  document.querySelectorAll(".row.docutils");
      for(let i = 0; i < testarray.length; i++){
         testarray[i].classList.add("my-class");
    }
 });
```