# how to unhide CSS element on input value change

Tags: javascript, html, css

on a web page I'm working on, I got an input area that I'd like to show a hidden CSS element (a DIV) when the input value is set to be greater than 1.

```html
<input type="text" class="NetscapeFix CalTicketQuantity form-control" name="tix_quantity" id="tix_quantity_1842" value="0" size="4" maxlength="4" onchange="calculate(this.form);">
```

above is the code snippet of the input field, also please see image attached to see how the input looks on the page. [Webpage Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rvkcw.jpg)

So, if you see the **image above**, what I'm trying to achieve is to show a div HIDDEN with CSS when "**Number of Individual Ticket Tickets:**" input is changed to be **greater than one**.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507138/how-to-add-a-class-to-a-given-element

Comment: What have you tried and what seems to go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Inside Calculate method you can add code to show your element,

If element div is hidden by CSS display = none

```
 document.getElementById("elementId").display = "block";
```

If element div is hidden by CSS visibility = hidden

```
 document.getElementById("elementId").visibility = "visible";
```

Comment: what do you mean inside the calculate method, how ?

Comment: It the method that invoke when text changed:    onchange="calculate(this.form)  ,      but you can add code any where you want

Answer (score 0):

try like below

```
//  hide / show - div
<div id="hidediv">hide this div</div>
....

<input type="text" class="NetscapeFix CalTicketQuantity form-control" name="tix_quantity" id="tix_quantity_1842" value="0" size="4" maxlength="4" onchange="calculate(this.form);">
.....

// script fun
calculate() {
    ...
    ....
    if(this.form['tix_quantity'].value>1) {
        document.getElementById("hidediv").display = "none";
    }else {
        document.getElementById("hidediv").display = "block";
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: No, unfortunately , non of these answers is working ..

Answer (score 0):

so you got a input field for a user to type a number into, if the user types a number greater then one into the box then unhide the div. that's actually pretty easy. you already got an onchange event that links to a function. all you need to do is place a simple if statement in that faction and use the line of code the other guy gave you.

if you put in the CSS display: none; then

```
if (ticket>1){
document.getElementById("tix_quantity_1842").display = "block";
}
```

if in the CSS it's visibility: hidden; then

```
if (ticket>1){
document.getElementById("tix_quantity_1842").visibility = "visible";
}
```