# how scanner works in pos system using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, point-of-sale

I have developed a pos system i have a product `product1 barcode = 12345` and `product2 barcode = 67890`  i want that when a user scan `12345` it should be clicked

```
<div id="cat-filter-plus-{{ '12345' }}" data-barcode="{{ '12345' }}" class="clciked">
 <a href=""><img></a>
</div>
<div id="cat-filter-plus-{{ '67890' }}" data-barcode="{{ '67890' }}" class="clciked">
 <a href=""><img></a>
</div>
```

any idea or someone share his example which he is applied in his pos will be thank full

Comment: pos scanners are usually treated as just keyboards as far as scanning and the hosting system is concerned. Write javascript to ensure a text input element has focus, monitor that input for the text that the scanner types, and take action accordingly.

Comment: yes i understand this but i want some example

Comment: Example of what?  How to listen for events on an input?  How to locate a div based on an attribute?  How to set a class?  (or is that how to fire an event)?

Comment: yes something like this

Comment: Off the top of my head, without any HTML provided, and with the data-barcode in a format that doesn't help yourself: `$(".pos").on("input", function() { $(\`[data-barcode="{{ '${$(this).val()}' }}"\`).addClass("clicked"); }`

Comment: Google is for examples. Asking on Stackoverflow is for if you cannot resolve a specific issue after having done research and trying to solve it yourself. If you have tried to solve it yourself, edit your question to include your attempt and state what the specific issue is with your attempts that you've encountered.

Comment: @Ouroborus there are lots of post like my post if u have no idea in ur mind you should not be here see this post he can also google it https://stackoverflow.com/q/507138/14913109 but he is also taking idea i am thankful to freedomn he is contributor

Comment: hi @freedomn-m you are adding class but it should not be add but it should be (#'cat-filter-plus-{{ '67890' }} div').click(); something like this thanks for your contributor

Comment: Which is why it's a throw-away comment.  *"it should be clicked"* when you already have `class=clciked` [sic] - so makes sense that you want to change that class.

Comment: To be clear: @Ouroborus *is* providing the *correct* response here - you'll see their comments have been upvoted.   See [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) - and include your research / attempts in the question.